# Full screen videoview without stretching the video

Tags: java, android, fullscreen, android-videoview

I wonder if I can get a way to let video run via videoview in full screen?

I searched a lot and tried many ways such as:

1. Apply theme in manifest:

   ```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
   ```

   but that does not force the video to be in full screen.
2. Apply in activity itself:

   ```
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   ```

   also does not force the video to be in full screen.

The only way force video to full screen is:

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
</VideoView>
```

This way it results in full screen video but it **stretches the video itself** (elongated video) ,

I'm not applying this improper solution to my videoview, so is there is any way to do it without stretching the video?

**Video Class:**

```
public class Video extends Activity {
    private VideoView myvid;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myvid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        myvid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
            +"/"+R.raw.video_1));
        myvid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myvid.requestFocus();
        myvid.start();
    }
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: By simply removing 4 android:layout_alignXXX in layout xml file should make your VideoView use as much screen space as possible while remain video's aspect ratio. This is how the API is design and suppose to work.

Comment: @yorkw i know that , normally it take 1/3 of screen with normal video display , also im not appling that xml with 4 android:layout_alignXXX to my app ,its an improper solution i found to force to full screen ,i want any proper  way to force it to be in full screen but(without stretching ) ,

Comment: I would assume this is the expected result. If you play in portrait mode, the video usually take full width but leave much space on top and bottom, if play in landscape mode, the video usually take full height but leave some space on side.

Comment: @yorkw android default player and many custom player play any video in full screen without spacing so that there must be a trick or code hack to do that and this what im looking for my dear

Comment: Do they still remain aspect ratio? I doubt that. there are many device which has different screen size. take Samsung Galaxy S2 as an example, the screen size is 480 x 800, which is 5:3 in landscape mode, which you can see is not a normal aspect ratio like 4:3 or 16:9.

Comment: use SurfaceView in XMl and use it

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38971707/1153703

Answer (score 48):

Like this you can set the properties of the video by yourself.

Use a SurfaceView (gives you more control on the view), set it to fill_parent to match the whole screen

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewFrame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </SurfaceView>
</Linearlayout>
```

then on your java code get the surface view and add your media player to it

```
surfaceViewFrame = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewFrame);
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDisplay(holder);
```

set on your media player a onPreparedListener and manually calculate the desired size of the video, to fill the screen in the desired proportion avoiding stretching the video!

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // Adjust the size of the video
    // so it fits on the screen
    int videoWidth = player.getVideoWidth();
    int videoHeight = player.getVideoHeight();
    float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;       
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceViewFrame.getLayoutParams();

    if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
    } else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
    }
    surfaceViewFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        player.start();         
    }

        }
    });
```

I modified this from a tutorial for video streaming that I followed some time ago, can't find it right now to reference it, if someone does please add the link to the answer!

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Ok, so, if you want the video to occupy the whole screen and you don't want it to stretch you will end up with black stripes in the sides. In the code I posted we are finding out what is bigger, the video or the phone screen and fitting it the best way we can.

There you have my complete activity, streaming a video from a link. It's 100% functional. I can't tell you how to play a video from your own device because I don't know that. I'm sure you will find it in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) or [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity implements Callback, OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener, 
    OnClickListener {   

private SurfaceView surfaceViewFrame;
private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayer";
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private ProgressBar progressBarWait;
private ImageView pause;
private MediaPlayer player; 
private Timer updateTimer;
String video_uri = "http://daily3gp.com/vids/familyguy_has_own_orbit.3gp";  


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videosample);       


    pause = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPauseIndicator);
    pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (player != null) {
        if (!player.isPlaying()) {
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    surfaceViewFrame = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewFrame);
    surfaceViewFrame.setOnClickListener(this);
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(false);

    progressBarWait = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarWait);

    holder = surfaceViewFrame.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
    player.setDisplay(holder);
}

private void playVideo() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(video_uri);
                    player.prepare();
                } catch (Exception e) { // I can split the exceptions to get which error i need.
                    showToast("Error while playing video");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }).start();     
}

private void showToast(final String string) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(VideoPlayer.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
}


public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    playVideo();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
//prepare the video
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {        
    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Adjust the size of the video
    // so it fits on the screen
    int videoWidth = player.getVideoWidth();
    int videoHeight = player.getVideoHeight();
    float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;       
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceViewFrame.getLayoutParams();

    if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
    } else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
    }
    surfaceViewFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        player.start();         
    }
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(true);
}

// callback when the video is over
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.stop();
    if (updateTimer != null) {
        updateTimer.cancel();
    }
    finish();
}

//pause and resume
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.surfaceViewFrame) {
         if (player != null) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.pause();
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                player.start();
                pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: FIRST OF ALL thanks for your answer , would you please write full code , because this is the first time i used videoview and never use surfaceview or MediaPlayer, im not expert in android , please also i cant understand this (manually calculate the desired size of the video, to fill the screen in the desired proportion ) , also i want finally when playing my videos in any mobile phone to occupy full screen without distortion or stretching , this question will be apart of big project so  my app will have many videos with different length and size , thanks alot

Comment: ALSO I ADD THIS LINE :final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.video_1);   then it play only audio of video not video it self , thanks

Comment: If the answer is what you seek for please don't forget to accept it! I'm glad I could help!

Comment: i test it , it does not gave me full screen video also when i change the uri to any other one it gave this Toast message :Error while playing video , any advice my dear

Comment: This code will resize the video but will not stretch it. if you want the video to be fullscreen I imagine you need several resolutions and you need to pick one that matches with your phone, but keep in mind I'm no expert in media playing. You can trace the exception and see what is wrong. My first guess is some broken link or mistype in the URI!

Comment: Just as an aside, I don't think there's any reason to go through all the SurfaceView crazyness. You can just use a VideoView like you normally would, but apply that sizing code to its LayoutParameters in the onPrepared callback.

Comment: It is absolutely appalling that there is no scaling mode like this, but thanks to the developers that this resizing works like it does.

Answer (score 4):

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
                String SrcPath = "/mnt/sdcard/final.mp4";
        videoView1.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
        videoView1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView1.requestFocus();      
        videoView1.start();     
    }
}




<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</VideoView>
```

try this it's working for me

Comment: Do you need all the alignment attributes if layout is fill_parent? Sounds like duplicates.

Comment: yes to set video view as full screen we need all the alignment,

Comment: This code makes the videoview fullscreen, but it stretches the video if the video is not an exact fit. This code doesn't maintains the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

The current upvoted solution works, but there may be a simpler solution to the original problem. A commenter correctly pointed out that you could resize a VideoView using the same methodology without the cost of converting everything to a SurfaceView. I tested this in one of my apps and it seems to work. Just add the calculated layout parameters to the VideoView in the OnPreparedListener callback:

mInspirationalVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               // mMediaPlayer = mp;

```
            mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    if(isPlaying = true) {
                        stopPosition = 0;
                        mp.start();
                        mVideoProgressTask = new VideoProgress();
                        mVideoProgressTask.execute();
                    }
                }
            });


            // so it fits on the screen
            int videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
            int videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
            float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;


            DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);

            float screenWidth = mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
            float screenHeight = mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;

            float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mInspirationalVideoView.getLayoutParams();

            if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
                lp.width = screenWidth;
                lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
            } else {
                lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
                lp.height = screenHeight;
            }

            mInspirationalVideoView.setLayoutParams(lp);

           ...

        }
    });
```

Comment: this worked for me exactly thanks. But the getwidth() & getheight() method depricated is there any alternative available???

Answer (score 2):

Here is my function which works for the full screen video without stretching it. It will automatically crop the sides of the video. It worked both portrait and landscape modes.

It was actually taken from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954658/scale-video-in-androids-videovideo).

```
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        int videoWidth = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
        int videoHeight = mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        float scaleY = 1.0f;
        float scaleX = (videoWidth * screenHeight / videoHeight) / screenWidth;

        int pivotPointX = (int) (screenWidth / 2);
        int pivotPointY = (int) (screenHeight / 2);

        surfaceView.setScaleX(scaleX);
        surfaceView.setScaleY(scaleY);
        surfaceView.setPivotX(pivotPointX);
        surfaceView.setPivotY(pivotPointY);

        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adjusting the underlying surface holder size? Try the code below it should adjust the surface holder to be the same width and height of the screen size. You should still have your activity be full screen without a title bar.

```
    public class Video extends Activity {
        private VideoView myvid;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            myvid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
            myvid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                +"/"+R.raw.video_1));
            myvid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            myvid.requestFocus();

            //Set the surface holder height to the screen dimensions
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            myvid.getHolder().setFixedSize(size.x, size.y);

            myvid.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it gave me red error under word : getSize in this line : display.getSize(size);

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hope it helps [FullscreenVideoView](https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView)

It handles all boring code about surfaceView and fullscreen view and let you focus only in UI buttons.

And you can use the FullscreenVideoLayout if you don't want to build your custom buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**A SurfaceView gives u an optimized drawing surface**

```
public class YourMovieActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private MediaPlayer media = null;
        //...

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            media = new MediaPlayer();
            mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
            //...
        }
    }
```

MediaPlayer calls should be wrapped in a try{}.

```
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        media.setDataSource("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
            +"/"+R.raw.video_);
        media.prepare();

            int videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        int videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

            int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

            android.view.

ViewGroup.LayoutParams layout = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();

    layout.width = screenWidth;

    layout.height = (int) (((float)videoHeight / (float)videoWidth) * (float)screenWidth);

    mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(layout);        

    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: [android.widget.VideoView implementation](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java#L107) is more robust and smarter than your implementation. It handles both case when video is too tall or too wide, so please just use VideoView.

Comment: but when u use views u can dynamically lay the parameters for the video which i thought u wer aiming at

Comment: @Yorkw: SurfaceView acts as a container .So u can add videoView inside it.So ur robustness still prevails.

Comment: No, you don't wrap VideoView within a SurfaceView, as VideoView itself is a SurfaceView `public class VideoView extends SurfaceView implements MediaPlayerControl {...}`. This is exactly the point why VideoView is provided by the API, to make your life more easier, as VideoView is sufficient for most of common use cases.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this one by **Custom VideoView**:

I have added VideoView to ParentView in two ways From xml & programatically.

Add Custom class for VideoView named with **FullScreenVideoView.java**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FullScreenVideoView extends VideoView {
    public FullScreenVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FullScreenVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FullScreenVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

How to **bind** with **xml**:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/secondMedia"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <com.my.package.customview.FullScreenVideoView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
           android:id="@+id/fullScreenVideoView"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**OR**

How to **add Programatically** VideoView to **ParentView**:

```
FullScreenVideoView videoView = new FullScreenVideoView(getActivity());
parentLayout.addView(videoView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this stretches the video

Comment: @MartyMiller, if video's resolution is small then it would stretch video, you can use HD video