# Android: Can I crop a video in aspect radio to fullscreen?

Tags: android, video, zooming, crop

I have learn how to resize video playing on this [Full screen videoview without stretching the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211837/full-screen-videoview-without-stretching-the-video) .

With `gameowner` answer, it works. And it also force to keep aspect radio such that it will end up with black stripes in the sides.

I would like to have another optional. That is I do not want to have black stripes in the sides. I would like the video height is still remain in screen height. To keep aspect radio, the video width should greater than screen width. It doesn't matter that I cannot watch the "most left part" and "most right part" of video.
I think I just need to change from:

```
if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
} else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
}
```

to

```
if (videoProportion < screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
} else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
}
```

would be ok but I didn't. 
Once the `surfaceView` size is larger than the screen. This just show black screen but keep aduio playing.

I also try to take surfaceview holder fixed size into account:

```
surfaceViewFrame.getHolder().setFixedSize(lp.width, lp.height);
```

but it does not solve the problem.
Is it possible to play video which size is greater than screen?

**Edit:** OK. I have realized that the term of my question. I would like to **zoom-in** my video in aspect radio and but in fullscreen. Also known as **crop** video to fullscreen.

I tried to use `TextureView` inside a `FrameLayout` (required) container:
[Playing video on TextureView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview)
I have Android 4.0 devices that work fine in this workaround but I am not sure it really work on other 4.0 devices. Also `TextureView` is Android 4.0 or above only. I would be grateful if there is workaround for Android 2.x.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem, did you manage to get this?

Comment: @shem. No. For Android 4 or above, we can use `TextureView` and resize it like normal view system. Or we can pre-process the video file first (like using [this](http://www.wondershare.com/video-editor/)), then load into android device.

Comment: Testing on modern device will not have this kind of issue.