# Android Full Width Video View

Tags: android, layout, video

I am trying to stretch my video view inside the linear layout to full screen but it doesn't match the device screen. Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="720dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
     android:layout_marginTop="140dp" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="720dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is always 10 to 15 dp space on left and right each. Also the Linear layout is not stretching to full screen. I want it to fill the screen in width.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12335916/598170

Comment: only this post http://blog.kasenlam.com/2012/02/android-how-to-stretch-video-to-fill.html solved my problem

Comment: @Taimur it is specific to `RelativeLayout` not for other layouts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get current height and width of the screen using display matrix

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Now use this height and width for your video view :)
use it programmatically not hardcode it like 720dp and all.
`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are deprecated by the google

Comment: Actually @rawD3buGGG3R's answer worked for me and i will suggest to set the parameters programatically to acheive desired implmenetation.

Comment: .getDefaultDisplay() and getDisplay are depricated it cause crash or issue from API 30 
what is the alternative for this

Answer (score 7):

Actually there's no need to set width programmatically

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Should suffice to fill the container with full width video view. And use match_parent instead of fill_parent. Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: What if you have to alter the displaymetrics at run time ?

Answer (score 2):

Get run time height and width of your layout and set that in `VideoView`

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();                  
//videoview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(550,550));                    
videoview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));

//FrameLayout : write your  layout name which you used
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fill_parent` in `android:layout_height` instead of using specific height.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```