# Cant play Video View Full Screen Android

Tags: android

I have placed Video View and Image View in FrameLayout i have a problem playing the video in full screen.

**SplashScreen Screenshot landscape:**[image: SplashScreen Screenshot landscape!]

**layout-land/splashscreen.xml**(Splashscreen layout for landscape):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <FrameLayout 
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >

       <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" ></VideoView>

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/welcomelogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/welcomelogo" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"  />

    </FrameLayout>
```

**layout/splashscreen.xml**(Splashscreen layout for portrait):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<FrameLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" ></VideoView>

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/welcomelogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/welcomelogo" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"  />

</FrameLayout>
```

**SplashScreen.java:**

```
package com.conquer.casino;

import com.conquer.casino.R;


import com.plattysoft.leonids.ParticleSystem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Relation;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    ImageView imageview;
    private RelativeLayout parent;      
    int modeChange;         
    private MediaController mc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
            //modeChange = 1;

        } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
            //modeChange = 2;

        }


        VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.trimmedvideo);

        mc = new MediaController(this);


        vd.setMediaController(mc);
        vd.setMediaController(null);
        vd.setVideoURI(uri);
        vd.start();

        // Start long running operation in a background thread
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                    try {

                        sleep(4000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
            }

        }.start();
    }


    /*public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            ParticleSystem ps = new ParticleSystem(this, 1000, R.drawable.starpink, 5000);

            ps.setScaleRange(0.7f, 0.3f);
            ps.setSpeedRange(0.01f, 0.55f);

            ps.setAcceleration(0.00001f, 10);
            ps.setRotationSpeedRange(1000, 580);
            ps.setFadeOut(10, new AccelerateInterpolator());
            ps.oneShot(v, 100);

    ParticleSystem ps1 = new ParticleSystem(this, 10000, R.drawable.starwhite, 5000);

            ps1.setScaleRange(0.7f, 0.3f);
            ps1.setSpeedRange(0.01f, 0.55f);

            ps1.setAcceleration(0.00001f, 10);
            ps1.setRotationSpeedRange(1000, 180);
            ps1.setFadeOut(10, new AccelerateInterpolator());
            ps1.oneShot(v, 500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new ParticleSystem(this, 100, R.drawable.starpink, 800)
        .setSpeedRange(0.1f, 0.25f)
        .oneShot(v, 100);
    }   */

}
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<![manifest][2] xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.conquer.casino"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="false"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:manageSpaceActivity="com.conquer.casino.ManageSpace"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.conquer.casino.SplashScreen"         
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!--  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|fontScale|uiMode" -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.conquer.casino.HomeActivity"

          android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.conquer.casino.GameListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|fontScale|uiMode"
          android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conquer.casino.GameActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|fontScale|uiMode"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.conquer.casino.ManageSpace"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|fontScale|uiMode"
          android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.conquer.casino.PlayForRealBtn"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|orientation|fontScale|uiMode"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mobileapptracker.Tracker"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4242000" /> <!-- 3136130 -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: May be this help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12335916/3048584

Comment: what is your problem? add some details please.

Comment: Can you state the nature of the problem?

Comment: Video is not playing in full screen i have posted the screenshot from the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason to use FrameLayout? 
I did it using RelativeLayout and its working fine and full screen. Below is code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </VideoView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/welcomelogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks got it with relative layout. Have a problem with orientation changes sorting it out now. Splash screen orientation is not changing.