# Set size of content video

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a video view of size 200dp by 200dp which retrives a video from firebase using url. Using uri.parse(url);

My problem is that the video that comes is of improper size it is usually smaller than videoview size.

**So how to change the size of video that is set to videoview**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211837/full-screen-videoview-without-stretching-the-video?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I dont want the video on full screen 
I want to set the video to 200x200 not the videoview @Mr. Roshan